# Error (task exception was never retrieved) when running discord bot commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using python, and I have run into an unexplainable error which I am unable to fix. I thought I fixed it by deleting the checks but I'm completely stumped by the massive block of errors I'm getting.
If anyone could please decode even some of this, I would be greatly appreciative.

Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='CommandTree-invoker' coro=<CommandTree._from_interaction..wrapper() done, defined at C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py:1089> exception=OperationalError('no such table: blacklist')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1091, in wrapper
await self._call(interaction)
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1242, in _call
await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\hybrid.py", line 436, in _invoke_with_namespace
await command.prepare(ctx)
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 919, in prepare
if not await self.can_run(ctx):
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\hybrid.py", line 524, in can_run
return await self.app_command._check_can_run(ctx.interaction)
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\hybrid.py", line 418, in _check_can_run
if self.wrapped.checks and not await async_all(f(ctx) for f in self.wrapped.checks):
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 674, in async_all
elem = await elem
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\Documents\rirakkumabot\main\helpers\checks.py", line 31, in predicate
if await db_manager.is_blacklisted(context.author.id):
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\Documents\rirakkumabot\main\helpers\db_manager.py", line 8, in is_blacklisted
async with db.execute("SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)) as cursor:
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiosqlite\context.py", line 41, in **aenter**
self._obj = await self._coro
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 184, in execute
cursor = await self._execute(self._conn.execute, sql, parameters)
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 129, in _execute
return await future
File "C:\Users\mitsuk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 102, in run
result = function()
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blacklist

Answer (score 0):

In the file **C:\Users\mitsuk\Documents\rirakkumabot\main\helpers\db_manager.py**, **line 8**

```py
async with db.execute("SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,)) as cursor:
```

**Error message**

```py
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blacklist
```

This error means that there's no table named `blacklist` in the database; you may want to create it before accessing it.